# Send different attachment files such as picture, pdf, audio files, video files and zip files via email in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a platform (e-commerce website) where I do upload different types of files and then I send them to users based on requests via email. I did try but get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError at /some-url/[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/book_file/selfish_gene.pdf'
```

I got some help regarding sending pdf files via email but that one is not working as well.
I do appreciate any guidance and help in advance regarding sending other files such as audio, picture, and video via email in Django.

Below I do provide a snippet of the code. Hope it helps.

Model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
 title           = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 author           = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 isbn           = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 page           = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)


class BookFiles(models.Model):
 book = models.ForeignKey(Book, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
 file = models.FileField(upload_to='book_file/', null=True, blank=True)
```

View:

```
def send_book(request):
 message = 'body of this email'
 subject= 'the subject of this email'
 recipient_email = 'customer@example.com'
 from_email = 'platformemail@example.com'
 email=EmailMessage(subject,message,from_email,[recipient_email])
 email.content_subtype='html'
 
 the_domain = request.build_absolute_uri('/')[:-1]
 book_object = Book.objects.get(title='Selfish Gene').bookfiles_set.all().first().file.url
 the_file=open(f'{the_domain}{book_object}',"r")
 email.attach("file_name.pdf", the_file.read(),'application/pdf')

 email.send()
```

Answer (score 1):

just remove the `.url` from `book_object` and send the `book_object.read()`

```
def send_book(request):
    subject= 'the subject of this email'
    message = 'body of this email'
    recipient_email = 'customer@example.com'
    from_email = 'platformemail@example.com'
    email=EmailMessage(subject,message,from_email,[recipient_email])
    email.content_subtype='html'

    # the_domain = request.build_absolute_uri('/')[:-1]
    book_object = Book.objects.get(title='Selfish Gene').bookfiles_set.all().first().file
    # the_file=open(f'{the_domain}{book_object}',"r")
    email.attach("file_name.pdf", book_object.read(),'application/pdf')

    email.send()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the MEDIA_ROOT in your settings.py to the absolute path to where the files resides on the disk? And , if so, what is it set to?

As a reference to media settings in Django, have a look at this article:
https://testdriven.io/blog/django-static-files/#media-files